# Rails console doesn't run on ec2 after deployment with rubber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, amazon-ec2, rails-console

I deployed my application on ec2 using rubber and it works fine, however when i try to run the console (typed rails console) it didn't work. It didn't recognize the scipt at first and when i tried to run it from the script directory I got a "couldn't find ruby.exe" message.
Any ideas?

Comment: did you run the rails command from the root of your app?

Comment: yes I did. I ran it from the root for the current directory of the deployment. Tried different directories (the release directory) but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run it with:

> bundle exec rails c

Comment: good call - this should probably do it. bundle exec runs rails with the current environment (including gems etc)